When does HDMI TMDS apply inversion on first 8 encoded bits?
According to Wikipedia, in the second stage of TMDS the first 8 bits encoded either with xor or xnor may be inverted. It further mentions that while the xnor/xor encoding aims to minimize transitions, the inversion step aims to even out number of zeros and ones. I don't understand, how is that different?

Please ask only one question per question. I've answered your first question (how minimizing transitions and evening out zeros and ones are different), but I don't know enough about HDMI/TMDS to answer the second.

There is a clear difference between minimizing the transitions and evening out the number of zeroes and ones.
For example a byte 10101010 has the maximal amount of transitions but equal amount of ones and zeroes so the imbalance for DC bias is zero. And byte 00000000 has minimal amount of transitions, but as it has no ones and eight zeroes the DC imbalance is -8.
That is why you first encode the byte with XOR or XNOR whichever produces the least transitions and mark which algorithm was used into 9th bit.
Then the encoded symbol can have an equal or unequal number of ones and zeroes, so you must keep track how much current imbalance of ones and zeroes is to choose if you want to increase it from negative towards zero or decrease from positive towards zero. Then you can choose to invert or not the 9-bit symbol and mark the inversion with the 10th bit.
The algorithm is described in more detail in respective specifications such as DVI and HDMI standards. The symbol is encoded as a whole based on the input byte and the current running disparity, it is well possible that the implementation as described by Wikipedia as two separate steps is also possible but just a naive approach.

An answer to your first question (please remove the second question and make it a separate question, to comply with site rules):
In NRZ line codes like TMDS, minimizing transitions and evening out zeros and ones are completely different operations. The sequence 101010101010 has exactly the same number of zeros and ones, but has the maximum possible number of transitions per bit.
Meanwhile, the sequence 111111000000 also has the same number of zeros and ones, but has only one transition in twelve bits.
This only applies to certain line codes, TMDS among them. Some other line codes encode the data in either the timing or the number of transitions, which has some advantages (it's a very simple way to make any arbitrary bitstream self-clocking, for instance).
